# oracle sql create recursive hierarchy from text

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

How to create a hierarchy from columns only with text like this.

This is the example query for which i want to create ther hierarchy.
The level is undefined so it should be a recursive statement.

```
select 'MP_STAGE1' mapping_name, 'table_a' target_table, 'input' inout from dual
UNION ALL
select 'MP_STAGE1' mapping_name, 'table_b' target_table, 'input' inout from dual
UNION ALL
select 'MP_STAGE1' mapping_name, 'table_c' target_table, 'output' inout from dual
UNION ALL
select 'MP_STAGE2' mapping_name, 'table_aa' target_table, 'input' inout from dual
UNION ALL
select 'MP_STAGE2' mapping_name, 'table_dd' target_table, 'output' inout from dual
UNION ALL

select 'MP_CORE1' mapping_name, 'table_c' target_table, 'input' inout from dual
UNION ALL
select 'MP_CORE1' mapping_name, 'table_dd' target_table, 'input' inout from dual
UNION ALL
select 'MP_CORE1' mapping_name, 'table_ee' target_table, 'output' inout from dual
UNION ALL

select 'MP_CORE2' mapping_name, 'table_a' target_table, 'input' inout from dual
UNION ALL
select 'MP_CORE2' mapping_name, 'table_b' target_table, 'input' inout from dual
UNION ALL
select 'MP_CORE2' mapping_name, 'table_dd' target_table, 'input' inout from dual
UNION ALL
select 'MP_CORE2' mapping_name, 'table_ff' target_table, 'output' inout from dual
UNION ALL

select 'MP_MART1' mapping_name, 'table_b' target_table, 'input' inout from dual
UNION ALL
select 'MP_MART1' mapping_name, 'table_dd' target_table, 'input' inout from dual
UNION ALL
select 'MP_MART1' mapping_name, 'table_ee' target_table, 'input' inout from dual
UNION ALL
select 'MP_MART1' mapping_name, 'table_ff' target_table, 'input' inout from dual
UNION ALL
select 'MP_MART1' mapping_name, 'table_gg' target_table, 'output' inout from dual;
```

Result from query to create hierarchy:

```
MAPPING_NAME    TARGET_TABLE    INOUT
MP_STAGE1       table_a         input
MP_STAGE1       table_b         input
MP_STAGE1       table_c         output
MP_STAGE2       table_aa        input
MP_STAGE2       table_dd        output
MP_CORE1        table_c         input
MP_CORE1        table_dd        input
MP_CORE1        table_ee        output
MP_CORE2        table_a         input
MP_CORE2        table_b         input
MP_CORE2        table_dd        input
MP_CORE2        table_ff        output
MP_MART1        table_b         input
MP_MART1        table_dd        input
MP_MART1        table_ee        input
MP_MART1        table_ff        input
MP_MART1        table_gg        output
```

Goal 1:

```
MAPPING_NAME    TARGET_TABLE    INOUT   hierarchy 
MP_STAGE1       table_a         input   1
MP_STAGE1       table_b         input   1
MP_STAGE1       table_c         output  2
MP_STAGE2       table_aa        input   1
MP_STAGE2       table_dd        output  2
MP_CORE1        table_c         input   2
MP_CORE1        table_dd        input   2
MP_CORE1        table_ee        output  3
MP_CORE2        table_a         input   1
MP_CORE2        table_b         input   1
MP_CORE2        table_dd        input   2
MP_CORE2        table_ff        output  3
MP_MART1        table_b         input   1
MP_MART1        table_dd        input   2
MP_MART1        table_ee        input   3
MP_MART1        table_ff        input   3
MP_MART1        table_gg        output  4
```

Better to achieve this Goal2:

```
MAPPING_NAME    PARENT_TARGET_TABLE TARGET_TABLE
MP_STAGE1       table_a             table_c
MP_STAGE1       table_b             table_c
MP_STAGE2       table_aa            table_dd
MP_CORE1        table_c             table_ee
MP_CORE1        table_dd            table_ee
MP_CORE2        table_a             table_ff
MP_CORE2        table_b             table_ff
MP_CORE2        table_dd            table_ff
MP_MART1        table_b             table_gg
MP_MART1        table_dd            table_gg
MP_MART1        table_ee            table_gg
MP_MART1        table_ff            table_gg
```

Comment: Please edit your question explain your logic.

Comment: The "Better to achieve" is a simple self-join on `parent_.mapping_name = child_.mapping_name and parent_.inout = 'input' and child_.inout = 'output'`. Below is a better answer that does the same in one table scan, but requires thoughtful reading to understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT mapping_name,
       parent_target_table,
       target_table
FROM   (
  SELECT mapping_name,
         target_table AS parent_target_table,
         MAX(CASE inout WHEN 'output' THEN target_table END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY mapping_name) AS target_table,
         inout
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  inout = 'input';
```

Or a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT mapping_name,
       PRIOR target_table AS parent_target_table,
       target_table
FROM   table_name
WHERE  LEVEL = 2
START WITH inout = 'input'
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR mapping_name = mapping_name
AND    PRIOR inout = 'input'
AND    inout = 'output';
```

Or, from Oracle 12, `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY mapping_name
  ORDER     BY inout, target_table
  MEASURES
    FIRST(input.target_table) AS parent_target_table,
    output.target_table AS target_table
  AFTER MATCH SKIP TO NEXT ROW
  PATTERN ( input+ output $ )
  DEFINE
    input  AS inout = 'input',
    output AS inout ='output'
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (mapping_name, target_table, inout) AS
SELECT 'MP_STAGE1', 'table_a',  'input'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_STAGE1', 'table_b',  'input'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_STAGE1', 'table_c',  'output' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_STAGE2', 'table_aa', 'input'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_STAGE2', 'table_dd', 'output' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_CORE1',  'table_c',  'input'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_CORE1',  'table_dd', 'input'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_CORE1',  'table_ee', 'output' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_CORE2',  'table_a',  'input'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_CORE2',  'table_b',  'input'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_CORE2',  'table_dd', 'input'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_CORE2',  'table_ff', 'output' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_MART1',  'table_b',  'input'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_MART1',  'table_dd', 'input'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_MART1',  'table_ee', 'input'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_MART1',  'table_ff', 'input'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MP_MART1',  'table_gg', 'output' FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

> | MAPPING_NAME | PARENT_TARGET_TABLE | TARGET_TABLE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | MP_CORE1 | table_c | table_ee |
> | MP_CORE1 | table_dd | table_ee |
> | MP_CORE2 | table_dd | table_ff |
> | MP_CORE2 | table_b | table_ff |
> | MP_CORE2 | table_a | table_ff |
> | MP_MART1 | table_ff | table_gg |
> | MP_MART1 | table_ee | table_gg |
> | MP_MART1 | table_dd | table_gg |
> | MP_MART1 | table_b | table_gg |
> | MP_STAGE1 | table_a | table_c |
> | MP_STAGE1 | table_b | table_c |
> | MP_STAGE2 | table_aa | table_dd |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ae5096a4eee572798dbf244b8a691ee6)*